# Are role="radiogroup" and role="radio" really necessary?

Tags: html, radio-button, wai-aria

There are some ARIA tutorial websites use non-semantic markup and some javascript to demostrate the use of `role="radiogroup"` and `role="radio"` such as the following example:

```
<ul role="radiogroup">  
    <li tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false">  
        <img role="presentation" src="radio-unchecked.gif">
        Option1
    </li>  
    <li tabindex="0"  role="radio" aria-checked="true">  
        <img role="presentation" src="radio-checked.gif">
        Option2
    </li>  
</ul>
```

But what's the point to use those `role`s when we already have semantic and javascript-less approach like:

```
<ul>  
    <li>  
        <input  id="opt1" type="radio" name="opt" value="1">
        <label for="opt1">Option1</label>
    </li>  
    <li>  
        <input  id="opt2" type="radio" name="opt" value="2">
        <label for="opt2">Option2</label>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because there are some people who really, really want custom designs for their form controls and will replace them with images and a pile of JavaScript regardless of there being semantically appropriate elements.

The roles just allow the damage to be mitigated when they do so.

Comment: While the first code is semantically correct too, it's a clear example of completely customized controls that work with JavaScript. The "aria" properties and attributes are included for accessibility (screen readers and other technologies) like @Denis Chenu said in his answer. 

For those interested, here's more info: [link] (http://w3c.github.io/aria-in-html/)

Answer (score 7):

In the second version : you need a role="radiogroup" on the ul.

Or better for accessibility : use a fieldset.

aria is not for semantic, it's for accessibility.

Comment: Fieldsets are difficult and in some cases impossible to style particularly with flexbox

Comment: And ? Still : fieldset is better for a11y … role can replace but not better.